# How to cleanup unnecessary comments after clarifying question?

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1435233/255648) a kind user gave me several tips to clarify my question. Now that I've clarified my question, these comments make no sense.

Is there a way to cleanup these comments? Shall I flag the comments, Or it's better to let them be there.

Comment: Once the comments are cleaned up, it might be nice to edit a note into your question, acknowledging the help of the commenter.

Comment: If the comments might be helpful in clarifying some point to a later reader, you might simply leave the comments if no one has incorporated them into the question or one of the answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the comment exchange is fresh, you can leave a comment along the lines of

> @friendlyUser Thanks for helping me to clarify the question. Since these comments are now obsolete, removing them would reduce the clutter on this page. I have already removed mine. [or: I will remove mine]

Then the other user may delete their comments, and all is nice. If the comment exchange is older, it may be found annoying to be called back to it by such a comment, so I would not particularly recommend that for older exchanges.

You can always flag and request a moderator clean up the comment thread. It's better to custom-flag and request a general clean-up than flagging each single comment in the thread as obsolete when the thread is longer, for two or three comments, either is fine. But if there are several comment threads at a post, and only one shall be cleaned up, it helps to be told which comments are obsolete, so then a flag on each obsolete comment may nevertheless be preferable if you can't concisely characterise the obsolete comments in a single flag message [like "comments of userXXX are obsolete, the issue has been resolved"].

(In the linked question, there is nothing left to do.)

Comment: This older post seems to be related to flagging comments as obsolete: [Preferred course of action for flagging of multiple obsolete comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9724/preferred-course-of-action-for-flagging-of-multiple-obsolete-comments)